# UWP front end with a COM backend

Tags: c++, uwp, com

I'm a student working on a diy scientific computing engine. I would really like to develop using the UWP XAML UI. Nothing else. I just want to consume the front end from a standard COM DLL. I need access to things like MySQL/Cluster and dynamic loading. I am quite proficient in COM. UWP and windows runtime component sandboxing is counter productive for me. VS2017 is awesome. XAML is awesome. This is not a store app. I just need to wrap basic event calls that wouldn't need to marshal anything more complicated than a string or a float. I can't seem to nail down an appropriate consice approach. Is there an approach that is supported by the relevant community?

Comment: My only reason for not using WPF of the go has been fear of it being dropped by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the recently announced XAML Islands at the //Build 2018 Conference, you will be able to create XAML UserControls and host them on your Win32/.NET framework applications (ie: Winforms or WPF).  This technology is currently in preview and supports the XAML WebView control, allowing Win32/.NET apps to have a fully HTML5 rendering engine.

For more information take a look at:

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/05/07/modernizing-applications-for-our-multi-sense-multi-device-world/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls

To address your WPF longevity question, our focus is on improving the UWP platform, but we do realize many companies have application assets in Winforms and WPF, so our goal is to ensure developers can interop with our new technologies.  You might want to investigate the .NETCore3 roadmap to learn more.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

Hope this helps,

Adam Braden [MS]

Comment: Thank you. This answers all of my questions. I suspected as much. I will code a WPF front end short term, and re-port it when the technology is right. The front end for sure, is not my deal breaker. Having to terminate my software in the future, because sandbox kills non-app construction, is my deal breaker. I'd prefer to not have to move to Linux.